# Importing CocoaPod into Swift Playground Produces Expression Failed to Parse Error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-playground

I have several private pods that I'm already using successfully in my project. I added a Swift playground to the workspace (not to the project), and I've added an `import Foo` statement to the top of the playground.

Autocomplete is working for my pod modules, so things seem to be set up correctly. However, I'm getting this very obscure error:

```
expression failed to parse, fixed expression suggested:
  #sourceLocation(file: "Foo.playground", line: 1)
```

It doesn't matter which line I put my import statement on; it always refers to line 1.

There is notably some Obj-C code in the framework that’s being imported. I’m not sure if that matters or not since it’s callable from the Swift in my app.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update (7/21/19):** Still haven't been able to resolve this, but I was able to confirm that a much simpler Obj-C library is callable from a playground. So, it's just the complex one I was trying to call initially. Since this is proprietary, there's not a lot of info I can share, but if anyone has suggestions on what to try (or what I can genericize, extract, and share here), I'm happy to take a stab at it and update you. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue with a playground that's included in my workspace and trying to make calls from a framework I'm developing.

Comment: @mrwheet Unfortunately not, I'm sorry! I ended up just abandoning the effort